# Using Korean characters in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, utf-8, intellij-idea

So I'm trying to use some Korean text in an Android project through Android Studio. The issue I'm running into is that when I declare a string such as: String test = "이"; during debug the string displays like this: ◰, but when right click and "View Text" i see "이", instead of the box.

I have the entire project configured to use UTF-8, but this doesn't seem to help matters. I'm wondering if it's a font issue in the code-viewer but I'm not sure.

Edit: I tested the same thing with Intellij, and the same problem exists.

Comment: I am not sure in Android Studio, but in Eclipse you can configure console log under `Run Configuration > Common` then change Encoding to `UTF-8`.

Comment: Thanks! Mark Vedder posted a solution that worked for me below. It had to do with the UI font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the code editor, make sure you have a font that supports the character set configured in *File > Settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) > [IDE Settings] > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Font*

For the console output, make sure you have a font that supports the character set configured in *File > Settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) > [IDE Settings] > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Console Font*

As for the text in the debugger... the debugger text uses the IDE's UI font to display text Strings rather then the editor's font. To correct the problem, first, make sure that the IDE Encoding is set to use UTF-8 in *File > Settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) > [Project Settings] > File Encodings > "IDE Encoding"*. (You may also want to set this in File > Other Settings > Default Settings... so any future new projects have it set.) That alone works for some. For others however, they also need to change the UI Font in *File > Settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) > [IDE Settings] > Appearance > "Override default fonts"* and restart IDEA. Even that appears to only work for some. I recommend you vote for and post some comments on the bug report [Debugger doesn't display unicode characters properly](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-72849)

Comment: Phew! That was an extensive response, thanks a lot, Mark. Not only was it extensive, it was useful. The font of the UI is what fixed it for me. (File > Settings > Appearance > Override default fonts by (not recommended). I swapped the default out for "Batang" which I googled, and found to be a font that supported Korean, and it works! I will still report this bug.

Thanks again, Mark. You're the best.